# Figuring out function arguments of a webservice function

Tags: php, nusoap

For reasons beyond my control, I'm forced to use `NuSoap` instead of `SOAP` to make a request to a webservice.

After some searching, I found `SOAP's` `__getFunctions()` equivalent in `NuSoap`. The part where I'm stuck now is to figure out in what format are the parameters expected by the webservice's function.

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/nusoap.php');    
$baseurl = 'http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL';    
$client = new nusoap_client($baseurl, true);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    die();
}
$proxy = $client->getProxyClassCode();
print_r($proxy);
```

The above is giving me an output of

```
class nusoap_proxy_1027585735 extends nusoap_client 
{ 
    // http://www.webservicex.net/:GetGeoIP^ 
    $parameters function GetGeoIP($parameters) 
    { 
        $params = array('parameters' => $parameters); 
        return $this->call('GetGeoIP', $params, 'http://testuri.com', 'http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP');  
    } 
    // http://www.webservicex.net/:GetGeoIPContext^ 
    $parameters function GetGeoIPContext($parameters) 
    { 
        $params = array('parameters' => $parameters); 
        return $this->call('GetGeoIPContext', $params, 'http://testuri.com', 'http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIPContext'); 
    } 
}
```

So now that I know the function names (GetGeoIP and GetGeoIPContext), I'm struggling to find out what parameters do I need to pass to those functions.

I'm guessing `$params = array('parameters' => $parameters);` is the part I should be interested in, but that isn't giving the complete picture.
So in short, is there `SOAP's` `__getTypes()` equivalent in `NuSoap`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SoapUI to get an example of the request.

If you create a new project with your url endPoint (WSDL) you can get all the soapCalls. With it is more easy to understand the types define in the WSDL.

Follow this link http://www.soapui.org/SOAP-and-WSDL/working-with-wsdls.html

$parameters is an array (key -> value) for each param in the request

$parameters = array('IPAddress' => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')

Comment: Due to a particular reason, I'm required to use nuSOAP only.

Comment: Sorry for my English, but SoapUI is only a tool software for your help. It isn't a librarie. You can use nuSOAP.

Answer (score 0):

`$opdata = $proxy->getOperationData('GetGeoIP');` The method getOperationData is inherited from nusoap_client. See http://www.contao-docs.org/docs/nusoap/html/classnusoap__client.html.

Comment: I know I can find out the parameter by going through the WSDL. What I was looking for is a way to find that out dynamically, i.e. have nuSOAP figure it out and let me know of it